# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

> Due to an error on our side, we accidentally announced the wrong winner of this election. After looking at the [detailed results](https://www.opavote.com/results/6500053927591936), I discovered the problem. Since BrettFromLA was a very close second, I decided to appoint Chenmunka *and* keep Brett on as moderator. I'm sorry for the confusion and the error.

Lifehacks's [first moderator election](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderators are:

[image: BrettFromLA] [image: Chenmunka]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking J. Musser who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6500053927591936).

Comment: Dear Ones, Thank you all for helping shepherd a fine effort for our mutual enjoyment.

Comment: Two for the price of one - good move!

Comment: Your mistake is our gain. This is wonderful news. You made my day (by accident) which is great.

Comment: The [OpaVote link](https://www.opavote.com/results/65000539275919360) in your question is dead. Also, the [election page](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/election/) lists only Brett as the winner. More consequences of the miscount muckup? Can we actually see who got how many votes? (cc @JonEricson)

Comment: @Randal'Thor: I fixed the link in the post and added Chenmunka to the election page. The problem is that these elections are still half automated and half manual. This is on the roadmap to fix, thankfully.

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations BrettFromLA!! I have seen you quite active here answering and in review queues.

Also Congratulations Chenmunka!!

Welcome to moderatorship!

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me, AJ!

Answer (score 7):

I'm kind of surprised I won, and a little intimidated! For example, I've never read the FAQ's, and I've never been to any chat pages or meta pages. So every time someone posts a link now, I'm saving it to a file on my desktop.

It'll take me a week or two to get up to speed, but I promise to "use my powers for good". (I sincerely mean that; I just put it in quotes because it sounds cheesy!) Thanks for welcoming me to the team!

Comment: I'm not at all surprised. Congratulations. Diamonds are a site's best friend. : ^ )

Comment: You were always the top candidate in my book, once you self nominated. Don't stress about anything, number one in the job description is take care of yourself first.  The diamond comes with lots of helpful resources, use them as needed.

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: Congratulations and have fun digging through all the helpful resources! Many of us have a “useful resources” file, bookmarks,... Your fellow mods on the site probably already welcomed you to the mod-only site chat and the TL. Enjoy, take your time, and remember: most regular mod actions can be undone ;-)

Comment: @Stephie Thanks for the welcome and the reassurance! I've closed (or maybe deleted?) a few questions that were already on hold, so it's good to know that if I messed up y'all can fix my mistake. There was also an awkward situation with a new user blaming us for not wanting to answer his question, and being rude to someone nice (I think it might have been YOU being nice!), but I didn't have a clear sense of how disruptive the new user's messages were so I left it as it was.

Answer (score 5):

There's a turnup!

Just returned home from a three day trip, during which I'd seen Brett's victory on my phone.  Preparing to congratulate him I noticed a diamond.

Thanks to everyone who voted.  And thanks for the words of support, they are appreciated.  Now to support this community - and congratulations Brett.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations Chenmunka. A diamond becomes you. Wearing two is a fine declaration and a rare distinction. I heartily welcome you to the crew.

Comment: Three, actually ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor  I'm blown away (figuratively). What a wonderful addition - another 'prime' number.